# Terminal flux of infinite spaghetti

Tags: magic, physics

The story [Strega Nona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strega_Nona) presents the artifact of an [infinite spaghetti pot](https://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/scp-4503).  This pot, once activated, produces enough spaghetti to cover an entire town over the course of a day or two.  But this all occurs while the pot is upright.

Let's assume that the mechanism of this pot is that any open space within the pot is magically filled with a new whole spaghetti noodle.  The chance of a spaghetti noodle appearing in any area in any given instant is proportionate to the amount of empty space in that area of the pot.  Since spaghetti is round, it's impossible to achieve 100% packing, and it will be [even harder given the new pasta will be arranged randomly](https://mathoverflow.net/a/254226/61697).  Thus, even when the pot is upright, new spaghetti will be created periodically and displace existing spaghetti, causing it to overflow.

Let's also assume that the pot while upright can cover an Italian village in a single layer of spaghetti in 24 hours.  Taking [Italian Village, OH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_Village) as the canonical Italian Village, that's about 1 square kilometer.  Let's also assume that the spaghetti is created at precisely 2mm in diameter and 25cm in length.

Now, let's say we want to generate as much spaghetti as possible.  Naturally, the way to do this is to activate the pot and then invert it over a hopper with a conveyor belt or train of containers ready to receive it.

Once this system reaches equilibrium, how much volume of spaghetti does it generate per second (i.e the terminal flux of the system)?  What else do I need to specify for this question to even be answerable?

**Added details:**

- The pot is 40 liters in volume and semi-spherical (as shown on the cover of the book), with an opening 50cm in diameter.
- The pot will be inverted in a carefully controlled industrial setting; temperature and humidity can be any values desired, but default to 20C and 50% humidity.
- The pot produces pure spaghetti (no olive oil).

**Partial Solution:**
A spaghetti noodle takes up 0.785 ml of volume.  Thus, a full pot with perfect packing would hold around 51,000 spaghetti noodles.  Assuming a packing ratio of around 60%, we can say the pot holds 30,000 noodles.

To cover Italian village takes 4 billion spaghetti noodles.  Given this can be done in 24 hours, the upright pot generates about 46,000 noodles per second (which already seems impractically fast, but that's what the numbers say).  This is clearly a lower bound for the inverted pot.

This is where I get stuck.  An easy solution would be to say that the inverted pot, by merit of being empty at rest as opposed to 60% full at rest, generates noodles 150% faster, and thus generates 115,000 noodles per second.

But the pot isn't ever empty.  If noodles appeared continuously throughout the pot, and noodles are created at rest relative to the pot it would take the average noodle a tenth of a second to fall out of the pot.  I'm not sure how to convert this to an average density of noodles in the pot.

On the other hand, it feels intuitively like the upright pot should be slower at generating noodles for reasons other than the at-rest density of noodles in the pot.  Noodles need to actually get pushed out of the upright pot by newly created noodles.  Here's where we get into magic mechanics rather than physics.  It feels like the less pressure there is on a noodle, the easier it would be to appear.  To maximize spaghetti production, we should probably run this system in a vacuum.  But I have no idea what factor that adds to spaghetti production (the inverse of pressure yields an infinite factor when the system is run in a vacuum, which definitely seems wrong).

Comment: I feel like you should re-parameterize this question for puzzling.stackexchange. xD

Comment: Diameter of pot? Depth of covered town after 2 days? (Be glad it isn't spaghetti code that's being generated)

Comment: Is the sun shining, what's the relative humidity, is there olive oil involved in the cooking (i.e. how sticky is it). And most of all, how is this a worldbuilding issue?

Comment: This is a fun problem, but I fail to see how it's a worldbuilding problem. Moreover, while the OP has specified the problem in detail, they have made no attempt at solving it themselves - which of course would not be expected in puzzling.stackexchange, but is expected here.

Comment: I don't get the part about 'new spaghetti will be created periodically and displace existing spaghetti' - i thought noodles only appear where there are none?  ---- and: if the noodles only appear where there are none (thus not creating pressure - or do they displace the air of the volume they appear in?) - they would not flow faster than they can free-fall.

Comment: Do we imagine the noodles 'grow' from the bottom of the pot? Once each grows to a given length, it breaks off from the bottom of the pot?

Comment: @Gene I've added a partial solution and the particular gaps that I have.

Comment: A pot of pasta that continually generates pasta or a [magic pudding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_Pudding) that keeps regenerating itself upon being eaten. mmm, ... I think I'd prefer the pudding!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**About 1.8 million noodles per second**

According to this reference (http://chemicalengineeringnow.com/OrificesPrinciples.htm) the equation your looking for is -

> $\dot{m} = C A \sqrt{2 \rho (P_1 - P_2)}$

Where:

- $C$ is the orifice flow coefficient
- $A$ is the area of the pot opening
- $p$ is the fluid density
- $P_1$ is the upstream pressure on the pot opening
- $P_2$ is the downstream pressure on the other side of the pot opening (presumably 0)

We then have:

- $(P_1 - P_2) = \rho g h$ (where $h$ is the height of the pot)
- Spaghetti ($\rho$) is mostly water (1000 ${{kg} \over {m^3}}$)
- The radius ($h$) of a 40L half-sphere is $\sqrt[3]{(40 \times 2) \times 3 \div 4 \div \pi}$
- $C$ is 1 (assuming the pot is designed for this)
- $g$ is approximately 9.8 m/s/s
- $A$ is $\pi (0.5 \div 2)^2 = 0.196$ m-squared

Therefore, $(P_1 - P_2) \approx  26,150$ Pa
and $\dot{m} = 1 \times 0.196 \sqrt{2 \times 1000 \times 26150} = $ 1,417 kg per second. Or -

- about 1.4 cubic meters per second
- about 1,417 liters per second

Or, for noodle per second. Using the provided conversion of 51,000 noodles per 40 Liter pot, I get 1,275 noodles per liter... or, for a flow rate of 1,417 liters per second, about 1.8 million noodles per second.

Comment: The pot isn't 2.5 meters deep, so your P is a bit off. However, a centrifuge could be used to increase g and get more noodles.

Answer (score 0):

Just getting some information out of the way for explanation purposes. The pot can hold 30,000 noodles. The average noodle takes 1/10th of a second to fall from the bottom of the pot to the outer rim. And that's all of the information we need. The pot will fill in 1/10th of a second, and then continually produce the same amount. So the pot will produce 30,000 noodles every 1/10th of a second, or 300,000 noodles every second.